# uWSGI ImportError: Cannot import name Flask

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi, digital-ocean, wsgi

I'm following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04#step-4-%E2%80%94-configuring-uwsgi) tutorial from DigitalOcean to get Flask on a NGINX server, and when I run this command: `uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:5000 --protocol=http -w wsgi:app`, I get this error in the logs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from xerix import app
  File "./xerix.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect, jsonify, session, flash, url_for
ImportError: cannot import name 'Flask'
```

My wsgi.py file contains:

```
from xerix import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

The xerix.ini file contains:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 5

socket = xerix.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

What do I do?

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, fixed it by installing everything through `pip3`.